# Why are Trace characters regular functions on the Bernstein Variety?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Given a $p$-adic reductive group $G$ with Grothendieck group $R(G)$ and $f$ an element of the Hecke Algebra $H(G)$ we can consider the function $x: R(G) \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\pi \mapsto trace  \pi(f)$ (for $f \in H(G)$). It is stated

(condition (i) in 1.2 here, for instance: https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number55.pdf)

that $x$ restricted to the Bernstein variety of $G$ is a regular function. This should be easy, but I would appreciate an explanation of why this is true.

Comment: It's way less interesting than you think:  the analytic structure on the Bernstein spectrum comes from twisting by unramified characters.  If $f$ is the characteristic function of a coset of a compact, open subgroup, then $\operatorname{tr} (\pi \otimes \chi)(f)$ equals $\chi(g)\operatorname{tr} \pi(f)$ for any $g$ in the support of $f$.  The general result follows by writing an arbitrary $f$ as a combination of such characteristic functions.

Comment: @LSpice  Right, but I guess in general, one is considering something like $\mathrm{tr} I_P^G( \pi \otimes \chi)(f)$ and it wasn't clear to me how to deal with this induction.

Comment: Oh, right.  I'm a supercuspidals guy, and I just plumb forgot about parabolic induction.  I think that Theorem 2, p. 233, of van Dijk's "Computation of certain induced characters of $\mathfrak p$-adic groups" will do it, though it may be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262136/why-are-trace-characters-regular-functions-on-the-bernstein-variety#comment646829_262136), Theorem 2 of [van Dijk - Computation of certain induced characters of $p$-adic groups](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01429876) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=338277)) says, with the notation of that result, that
\begin{align*}
\Theta_{\mathrm{ind}_P^G(\rho\chi)}(f)
& = \int_M \chi(m)\int_K \int_N f(k m n k^{-1})\delta_P(m)^{1/2}\theta_\rho(m)\mathrm dn\,\mathrm dk\,\mathrm dm \\
& = \sum_{m \in M/K \cap M} \chi(m)\operatorname{meas}(K \cap M)\int_K \int_N f(k m n k^{-1})\delta_P(m)^{1/2}\theta_\rho(m)\mathrm dn\,\mathrm dk.
\end{align*}
(Actually the stated integral is in a different order, but each integral is compactly supported, so the interchange is OK.)  The sum is finite because $f$ is compactly supported.